# Elasticsearch not analyzed is missing on index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Every day I create the index on Elastic server which is hosted on AWS. Elastic Index format is `abcnoteyyyyMMdd`. You can look below the mapping result of Index.I am creating the index through ElasticSearch.Nest.

Index Creation Code:

```
          DateTime _instance = DateTime.Now;
      if (!(client.IndexExists("eccnote" + _instance.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))).Exists)
            {
                var createIndexResult = client.CreateIndex("eccnote" + _instance.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
                var mapResult = client.Map<ESNote>(c => c.MapFromAttributes().IgnoreConflicts().Type("esnote").Indices("eccnote" + _instance.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
            }
```

But there is some problem, I do not know what is it? An index is being created successfully. but someday I am getting  "index" : "not_analyzed" is missing from mapping results. For example here is the mapping result of Index dated 20160615. Here the result is in a proper format.

```
 GET  **indexname20160615**/_mapping?pretty        

  output result:- 
      {
   "indexname" : {
     "mappings" : {
         "type" : {
    "properties" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "account" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },

      "type" : {
        "type" : "integer"
      },
      "userid" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
         }
        }
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

But when I see the mapping result of index dated 20160614,It is showing like this. Here "index" : "not_analyzed" properties is missing. It is happening for the random day only. I do not know why?

GET  **indexname20160614**/_mapping?pretty

```
 {
indexname20160614" : {
"mappings" : {
  "indextype" : {
    "properties" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },

      "session" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "tn" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "type" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "userid" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
      }
      }
     }
   }
 }
```

Why is it happening?  Because every day through C# code, we create the index on ElasticServer but sometimes it is in proper format, sometimes it is not.

Comment: Maybe, you should show the C# code that creates the daily index, that would help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: DateTime _instance = DateTime.Now;
                client = new ElasticClient(settings);
                if (!(client.IndexExists("eccnote" + _instance.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))).Exists)
                {
                    var createIndexResult = client.CreateIndex("eccnote" + _instance.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
                    var mapResult = client.Map<ESNote>(c => c.MapFromAttributes().IgnoreConflicts().Type("esnote").Indices("eccnote" + _instance.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
                }

Comment: You should probably update your question instead, it'll be more legible.

Comment: question is simple .

Comment: I meant that your previous comment should go into your question so it can be properly formatted and easier to read.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Is it possible that another process could have created that index without the same mapping? In `indexname20160614` it doesn't look like you have the same fields (`session` and `tn` are different and `account` is missing`)

Comment: it's not missing . I have mentioned only some fields from POCO because it is too big .   but  I am little bit agree with you ,maybe it can possible that at that same time two process were trying to create the index .